# Как убрать связь многие ко многим?

Tags: база-данных, модель-данных, связь, многие-ко-многим

В универе курс СУБД. Задали составить ER-модель БД развивающего центра для детей. Почти все сделал, осталось только расправиться со связью между сущностью Родитель и сущностью Ребенок. Понятно, что связь многие ко многим. От нее нужно как-то избавиться. Но как это сделать, что можно добавить?

Comment: Я бы сдела не как много ко многим так как у ребёнка хоть и два родителя, но папа только один, так же как и мама.

Comment: Но что тогда получится, две сущности отец и мать? Но ведь у них тогда будут общие атрибуты. А какие атрибуты будут различаться? В задании даны атрибуты: ФИО, телефон и адрес проживания.

Comment: Сущность одна, просто у ребенка два поля "отец" и "мать" и оба ссылаются на одну и ту же таблицу родителей.

Comment: @Mike, я могу ошибаться, но Entity-Relation model вроде бы так и называется, потому что там связи между сущностями устанавливаются. Как мне установить связь между сущностью и отдельными атрибутами? Мне кажется, нужно добавить дополнительную сущность с дополнительной информацией, чтобы от родителя шла связь один ко многим и от ребенка такая же связь.

Comment: И что будет в этой отдельной таблице ? будут например два _атрибута_ ребенок и родитель. И связь с другими таблицами все равно будет конкретных атрибутов. всегда есть атрибут обеспечивающий связь

Comment: *у ребёнка хоть и два родителя, но папа только один, так же как и мама* А также приёмные родители (и теоретически - не одна пара...), а ещё - суррогатная мать... Никуда тут от M:N не деться - (child-parent-relationtype).

Comment: @Akina,  а еще есть вариант, когда у родителей не один ребенок,а несколько.